# Problems with heroku rake db:reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, rails-postgresql

I have a problem, I pushed my app to github and I made the deploy with heroku, everything was ok, but when I run `heroku run --app myapp rake db:reset` (to populate the database on heroku) I found the following messages filled with errors (I show only the part that I think is important because the message was too long)

```
FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
.
.
.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't drop d5q6ajst4p4d97
FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
.
.
.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"utf8", "database"=> [DATABASE], "pool"=>5, "username"=> [USERNAME], "password"=> [PASSWORD], "port"=>5432, "host"=> [HOST]}
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
   -> 0.0370s
-- create_table("heros", {:force=>:cascade})
   -> 0.0307s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0579s
```

**Note**: I'm hiding the username, password, etc...

Everything works fine in the deployed app, but I find ugly to see so many mistakes when making a `rake db: reset` in heroku, so after seeing this I searched how to solve this problem and found some posts that preach the same solution, so I followed the recommendations and run the command `heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL --app myapp`, it ended succesfully, but the same error message appears when I tried again to run `rake db:reset`, What could be happening?

**This is my database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: project_development
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: project_test
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: project_production
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku, being a *shared* service is not allowing users the permissions to `drop` nor `create` databases - hence the error when running `rake db:reset`

Hence `heroku pg:reset` is present as a command to perform the reset of your database.

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rake

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error I have fixed it by

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL
heroku rake db:migrate
```

As per you error

Also your database.yml point `postgres` user to connect database in heroku

it should not be postgres as a user in production mode.

so

> Active Record 4.1+ Escape Valve
>
> If you need need to connect to a different database than the
>   ENV['DATABASE_URL'] Rails 4.1+ supports a URL key in the database.yml
>   file that will take precedence.

```
production:
  url: <%= ENV["SOME_OTHER_URL"] %>
```